# Right button not showing after add left button and title

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I want to design naviation view like below image:

[image]

I am adding this code

```
func setupUpHomePageNavigation(title:String, subtitle:String) {

    let back_button = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic_logo"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.btnKbImageClicked))

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [back_button]

    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    space.width = 0.0

    let one = UILabel()
    one.text = title
    one.textAlignment = .left
    one.textColor = UIColor.black
    one.backgroundColor = .green
    one.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    one.sizeToFit()

    let two = UILabel()
    two.text = subtitle
    two.textAlignment = .left
    two.backgroundColor = .yellow
    two.textColor = .darkGray
    two.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    two.textAlignment = .center
    two.sizeToFit()


    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [one, two])
    stackView.distribution = .equalCentering
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .leading
    stackView.backgroundColor = .red

    one.sizeToFit()
    two.sizeToFit()

    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:150).isActive = true

    //self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [back_button,space,UIBarButtonItem(customView: stackView)]

    let account_button = UIBarButtonItem(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "user-silhouette"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.btnAccountClicked))
            account_button.tintColor = .black

    let search_button = UIBarButtonItem(image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "search (2)"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.btnSearchClicked))
    search_button.tintColor = .black


    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [account_button,search_button]

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is the "ic_logo" image size ?

I am asking for this because I tried multiple images for navigation bar button and :

[image]

using image of minimum 90*90 dimension and then it's 2x and 3x, I am getting above result. I am using the same code of your's. It's just I am changing the image size.

If I will increase the size further the space will increase. Ideally If you want to keep the left bar button icon on the left side the image size needs to be 30*30 or 40*40 and it's multiples. Then the UI will be perfect.

Try changing the "ic_logo" size.