# Increase height of Navigation bar and make round from bottom?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

Is it possible to create view like below image using default navigation bar  ? or i have to create custom View for this task ?

[image]

Adding Left and Right Buttons with Title i doing like

[Right button not showing after add left button and title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56505997/4466607)

I am doing :

```
 let height: CGFloat = 200
        let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.primaryColor

        let radius:CGFloat = 20.0
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner,.layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
```

Result :
[image]

i am unable increase the height of Navigation bar and Make it round from bottom .

please help

Comment: Show us how you failed so we can take it from there.

Comment: @Desdenova ,  Please check updated question , with Rounded bottom of navigation view , height is not increased .  i want to increase the height of navigation bar with round bottom

Comment: is it also possible using  `UINavigationBar.appearance()` so that i don't have to write every where , please help @Desdenova

Comment: suggest use the custom navigation bar

Comment: We cannot increase navigation bar height after iOS11, Instead create a view and complete your task..